# One Ip through an interface and all others through another

Tags: iptables

I have two interfaces, wlp5s4 and enp0s29f7u5.

I would like to only use enp0s29f7u5 for 192.168.8.1, but for any other traffic I would like to use wlp5s4 as enp0s29f7u5 isn't actually connected to the outside world.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to clarify your question. You say you want specific IPs on each interface, or you want to block traffic in a certain way? You interfaces are setup in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: your question is too broad, and you are asking for general concepts. We need also an `ifconfig -a`. Your enpxxx will be the internal interface, the wlpxxx the external one, and then you need to enable ip forwarding in the system, and NAT between the two. You also do not tell us your purposes, so this is the best I can say. Please do take time to detail your scenario to attract better answers.